# Best approach to build C# DLLs for different editions of a software?

Tags: c#, dll, versions

I have to build three different editions of a DLL which contain API calls of our software.  I have so far figured out the following way of doing it using inheritance. Can someone please confirm if I'm using inheritance the correct way (or if you have a suggestion for doing it a proper/better way?)  I am new to this so still learning C# project programming.

So far I have main class of API_calls (which are common for all DLL editions) as follows:

```
namespace APIcalls
{
  public partial class API_Calls
  {
    public void Common_function1()
    {
    }

    public void Common_function2()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

Then I have three .cs class files with something like the following in each of them (Edition_A, Edition_B, and Edition_C are the differing factors for each edition of DLL), any additional calls are included in **partial class API_Calls** as follows:

```
namespace dll_edition
{
 public class Edition_A
 {
    public Edition_A()
    {
      // Code here for checking if current DLL is authorized
      // Otherwise throw an exception
    }
 }
}

namespace APIcalls
{
  public partial class API_Calls : Edition_A
  {
    public void Additional_Edition_A_function1()
    {
    }

    public void Additional_Edition_A_function2()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

In each assembly build I include Edition_A file, or Edition_B file, or Edition_C file and then I build all three assemblies which gives me three DLLs.

My question:  Is this the proper way of doing it? Is there any negative about how I have done it? Or is there a better way of doing this?  My ultimate goal is to have three editions of DLL with some common API calls in them and then various API calls specific to each DLL type.

Thank you for any input that you may have!

-DD

Comment: Why not just have them all in one dll, and only allow access to the certain api calls based on what edition they're running, you would be maintaining only one code-base.

Comment: I did it to reduce the size of DLL (otherwise it was almost 12MB.)  There are over 400+ API calls all together so I wasn't sure if there was a better way of doing it - is there a better route?  I've got all files within the same solution, isn't that maintaining just one code-base?

Comment: Regarding clean code, there's a rule called FCoI: favor composition over inheritance. Perhaps you can try to understand it and use it in this scenario. Inheritance creates a strong coupling, which means it'll be hard to change it later on. Composition instead allows you to compose things in various different ways. It has a loose coupling and allows exchanging things, e.g. if you decide to change your licensing later.

Comment: @ThomasWeller If I understood that FCol correctly, even that seems to require everything to be built into one DLL, my goal is to create three smaller DLL depending on the edition, rather than one big one due to limit in size of embedded flash storage.

Comment: You just need the definitions of the interfaces in one DLL. You can then put the implementations into other DLLs if your concern is size. Make sure you distinguish role interfaces from header interfaces ([link](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/RoleInterface.html)). If you have the chance, use the trial period of Pluralsight and watch [Encapsulation and SOLID](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/encapsulation-solid) by Mark Seemann. For long term, work (not only read!) with the book Clean Code by Robert C. Martin. Thanks for being interested in learning clean code. I wish you all the best.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think that maybe a good idea for me to try out, I'm going to see if I can setup my DLL that way (I didn't realize that it was possible to put just definitions of interfaces in a DLL without putting all logic built into it too.  If this works out, I think this would actually work well for me because I'd just have to send customers two small DLLs.  Thank you- I'll repost once I figure this out and accept your suggestion as answer if it works well!

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have set of common functions in a common base class that is to be used by different other classes.

There are various ways of doing it with their own pros and cons:-

1) Creating seperate libraries for each type which you are doing, in which only limited functionality goes to end user and size of dll is small.This is better suited if you have dlls working on plus and play model where you just dump the dll in the bin amd new functiinality is in place.

This also makes your changes centric, so you know where your changes are. But what if you have distributed you dll to end clients and they need method in other dll, you again have to republish your changes.

2) Doing it all in 1 dll, unwanted functionality is exposed to client, deployment package could be heavy. But you have all the functionality readily available.

To summarize would mainly depend on your business and deployment model.

Comment: I can't use one DLL approach, our customers use it on an embedded processor board with very limited resources so flash storage is limited. Our dll is mature now with all needed calls (its almost 4 years old) so we won't have to revise DLL in future as any revision would require a new board (hardware.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I am a bigger fan of doing it all in one DLL and using a [Factory Pattern](https://www.dotnetperls.com/factory) to determine which version gets run at runtime, but if it must be 3 based on your requirements here is what I recommend.

Create 4 DLLs.

The first project will just contain the edition interface (e.g. The structure of the DLL, but no content on how it will work). This interface can be attached to the classes for the different versions of the DLL. Using this structure will set up the calling code so that it can use dependency injections for different editions of the DLL.

The other 3 DLLs will be the different editions of the DLL that you are required to build.

Comment: If I'm understanding it right from that link you provided, looks like Factory Pattern would require everything to be built into one DLL, one of my tasks is to reduce the DLL size as it is stored in an embedded board with limited resources. :-(

Comment: So then dependency injection looks like the route to go.  That's the second part of my answer, but after re-reading what I wrote it really didn't stick out.